# Different output from implementations of AES-256-CFB

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, aes

I have to decrypt already encrypted values. I know the setting used, the key and the iv, but keep getting wrong results. I know the encryption is done the same way as this online tool - https://appzaza.com/encrypt-text , which provides the right results, but cannot seem to find the reason why my output is different.
[image]

The settings:
Mode: CFB
KeySize: 256
Encoding: UTF-8

My code:

```
            static void Main()
            {
                string plaintext = "1515151515115129";
                string pass = "ncJ9JhWrXa9DqN1GzBCNlBoKs289Q1dD";
                string iveee = "jHGasOT60bJXcHdd";
                string message = "sdH9HhaLd8K8f0jBdOP/2g==";

                byte[] passBytes = (Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pass));

                // Create secret IV
                byte[] ivBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(iveee);

                string decrypted = DecryptString(message, passBytes, ivBytes);
            }

            public static string DecryptString(string cipherText, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
            {
                // Instantiate a new Aes object to perform string symmetric encryption
                //Aes encryptor = Aes.Create();
                using (var encryptor = Aes.Create())
                {
                    encryptor.Mode = CipherMode.CFB;
                    encryptor.KeySize = 256;
                    encryptor.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;

                    // Set key and IV
                    encryptor.Key = key;
                    encryptor.IV = iv;

                    byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);

                    // Instantiate a new MemoryStream object to contain the encrypted bytes
                    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(cipherBytes))
                    {

                        // Instantiate a new encryptor from our Aes object
                        using (ICryptoTransform aesDecryptor = encryptor.CreateDecryptor(key, iv))
                        {
                            string plainText = "";
                            // Instantiate a new CryptoStream object to process the data and write it to the 
                            // memory stream
                            using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, aesDecryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                            {
                                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(cryptoStream))
                                {
                                    plainText = sr.ReadToEnd();
                                }
                            }
                            return plainText;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Any ideas what might be the reason?

Putting the encryption code I am using for testing purposes:

```
        public static string EncryptString(string plainText, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
        {
            // Instantiate a new Aes object to perform string symmetric encryption
            Aes encryptor = Aes.Create();

            encryptor.Mode = CipherMode.CFB;
            encryptor.KeySize = 256;
            encryptor.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;

            // Set key and IV
            encryptor.Key = key;
            encryptor.IV = iv;

            // Instantiate a new MemoryStream object to contain the encrypted bytes
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

            // Instantiate a new encryptor from our Aes object
            ICryptoTransform aesEncryptor = encryptor.CreateEncryptor();

            // Instantiate a new CryptoStream object to process the data and write it to the 
            // memory stream
            CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, aesEncryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);

            // Convert the plainText string into a byte array
            byte[] plainBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);

            // Encrypt the input plaintext string
            cryptoStream.Write(plainBytes, 0, plainBytes.Length);

            // Complete the encryption process
            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();

            // Convert the encrypted data from a MemoryStream to a byte array
            byte[] cipherBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();

            // Close both the MemoryStream and the CryptoStream
            memoryStream.Close();
            cryptoStream.Close();

            // Convert the encrypted byte array to a base64 encoded string
            string cipherText = Convert.ToBase64String(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);

            // Return the encrypted data as a string
            return cipherText;
        }
```

I tried all the different modes of padding but without any result

Comment: try setting the feedback size to 64, e.g. `encryptor.FeedbackSize = 64;`

Comment: Just tried it, but didn't change the output

Comment: Using `PaddingMode.Zeros` is not guaranteed to work correctly if the last bit(s) of the plaintext are zeros.  Better to use padding mode PKCS#7, which is guaranteed to be cleanly removed.

Comment: I tried all the different modes of padding but without any result

Comment: Your EncryptString comes out with sR56187nS58ldV3yHovpVA==  which if you feed it back into DecryptString it works just fine. If you use AES-256-CFB8 on the website it works just fine.

Comment: Yes, but I need to decrypt values that are already encrypted with AES-256-CFB, I can't seem to find a way for my code to use  AES-256-CFB instead of  AES-256-CFB8

Comment: `encryptor.FeedbackSize = 128;` ? i'm not sure, it's weird IMO to use a 8 bit feedback by default, but i don't know API of the class you're using